# Java Byte.parseByte() error

Tags: java, parsing, byte, numberformatexception

I'm having a small error in my code that I can not for the life of me figure out.

I have an array of strings that are representations of binary data (after converting them from hex) for example:
one index is 1011 and another is 11100. I go through the array and pad each index with 0's so that each index is eight bytes. When I try to convert these representations into actual bytes I get an error when I try to parse '11111111' The error I get is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"11111111" Radix:2
```

Here is a snippet:

```
String source = a.get("image block");
int val;
byte imageData[] = new byte[source.length()/2];

try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);
    for (int i=0; i<source.length(); i+=2) {
        val = Integer.parseInt(source.substring(i, i+2), 16);
        String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(val);
        while (temp.length() != 8) {
            temp = "0" + temp;
        }
    imageData[i/2] = Byte.parseByte(temp, 2);
}
```

Comment: `byte`'s only allow numbers in the range of -128 to 127. I would use an `int` instead, which holds numbers in the range of -2.1 billion to 2.1 billion.

Answer (score 28):

Isn't the problem here that `byte` is a signed type, therefore its valid values are -128...127? If you parse it as an `int` (Using `Integer.parseInt()`), it should work.

By the way, you don't have to pad the number with zeroes either.

Once you parsed your binary string into an int, you can cast it to a byte, but the value will still be treated as signed, so `binary 11111111` will become `int 255` first, then `byte -1` after the cast.

Comment: In `Byte.parseByte(String s, int radix) throws...`, `s` is assumed as positive unless it has an explicit sign ('+'/'-') as the first character. According its [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-) documentation: "The characters in the string must all be digits, of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value) except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value."

Answer (score 1):

Well, eight one's is 255, and according to java.lang.Byte, the MAX_VALUE is 2^7 - 1 or positive 127.

So your code will fail because you number is too large. The first bit is reserved for the positive and negative sign.

according to [parseByte](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

`byte`'s only allow numbers in the range of -128 to 127. I would use an `int` instead, which holds numbers in the range of -2.1 billion to 2.1 billion.