# NumberFormat Exception to parse String to Byte?

Tags: java, byte

I am trying to parse the following String to Byte.But it gives me NumberFormat Exception.Can some body tell me what is the solution for this?

```
Byte.parseByte("11111111111111111111111110000001", 2);
```

Comment: Thats way larger than a byte.

Comment: A byte is made of 8 bits... each of your 0/1 chars is a bit.

Comment: DV - check javadocs before posting question.

Comment: and here's a dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996707/java-byte-parsebyte-error

Comment: If you still want to ignore overflows your option is to parse as int and then cast int to byte.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, Long.parse binary String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926920/java-long-parse-binary-string)

Answer (score 2):

Out of range of byte ie -128 to 127. From [parseByte(String s,int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) javadoc:

> ```
> public static byte parseByte(String s, int radix)throws NumberFormatException
> ```
>
> Parses the string argument as a signed byte in the radix specified by
>   the second argument. The characters in the string must all be digits,
>   of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char,
>   int) returns a nonnegative value) except that the first character may
>   be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value.
>   The resulting byte value is returned. An exception of type
>   NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations
>   occurs:
>
> 1. The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> 2. The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than
>      Character.MAX_RADIX.
> 3. Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix,
>      except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D')
>      provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> 4. The value represented by the string is not a value of type byte.
>
> Returns: the byte value represented by the string argument in the
>   specified radix Throws: NumberFormatException - If the string does not
>   contain a parsable byte.

Comment: This is not correct. `parseXXX()` methods handle binary string as sign-magnitude not as a 2's complement. See my answer.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: The answer here is correct, actually it's just copy/paste from javadoc without a link to it.

Comment: @jlordo I know and that is why I did not down-vote this answer. But they said `Parses the string argument as a signed byte` which IMHO is not quite true if radix = 2.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Yes, it's true. Java doesn't know unsigned bytes, so they say it parses the string argument as a signed byte. They nowhere say the first digit is the sign bit.

Answer (score 2):

`Byte.parseByte()` handles binary string as sign-magnitude not as a 2's complement, so the longest length you can have for a byte is 7 bits with a sign.

In other words, to represent `-127`, you should use:

```
Byte.parseByte("-111111", 2);
```

The following throws `NumberFormatException`:

```
Byte.parseByte("10000000", 2);
```

However, the binary literal of -127 is:

```
byte b = (byte) 0b10000000;
```

The same behavior is applied to the other `parseXXX()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

from javadocs

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the
>   following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
> - The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D')
>     provided that the string is longer than length 1.
> - The value represented by the string is not a value of type byte.

Your value is the second case that is out of range -128 to 127

Answer (score 0):

Value is too large to be parsed in *byte*
Try this:

```
new BigInteger("011111111111111111111111110000001", 2).longValue();
```